# GeoServer Raster Data Sources: satellite data's contrast issue

Tags: raster, geoserver, geowebcache

I am trying to use my own satellite image as the basemap for a webapp, instead of OSM, Google etc imageries. In order to do that, I made a `Raster Data Sources` store inside my GeoServer, which is pointing towards a .tif file (having .prj and .tfw files along-with). I am on Ubuntu 14.04. Everything is working fine except the following issue.

As can be seen in the attached images, visualization of satellite image in QGIS is giving a good contrast and brightness. But importing the very same image inside GeoServer is producing low contrast/bright image, plus seams, which can be seen at the bottom section. Although I am using `Tiling:Tiled` in the GeoServer, it shouldn't create seams. Zoomin and out are also changing the contrast and brightness of the GeoServer image.

[image: QGIS image]

[image: GeoServer image]

Can you explain the reason and remedy of this unexpected effect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a 16 bits image.

Quick suggestion, the easiest thing to do is to preprocess this image and perform color correction upfront.

You can use QGIS itself or GDAL utilities (See this email: http://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/gdal-dev/2012-March/032180.html)

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @simogeo, since the orginal data was in 16bit data type, there were seams and performance issues.

The following command from terminal will convert 16 to 8 bit data type, provided the lower and upper values of 16bit data (which is 156 and 4095 in my case).

```
gdal_translate -of GTIFF -ot Byte -scale 156 4095 0 255 -co worldfile=yes image_16bit.tif image_8bit.tif
```